# How to create a new image from a GroupLayer

Tags: playn

I added a couple of images into a GroupLayer. Does anyone know how to create an image from that GroupLayer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea:

> Surface.drawLayer(Layer layer);

*Renders the supplied scene graph into this surface. This renders the scene graph into the surface's texture using the main render pipeline, so custom shaders (on platforms that support them) are handled properly. NOTE: if there is a loop in the scene graph (like you add an ImmediateLayer that calls surf.drawLayer(graphics().rootLayer())) you will get the infinite loop that you deserve. Caveat renderer.*